# How to convert a UIElement which is created in code behind into stream using C#?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have created UIelements dynamically in code behind without using Xaml and I need to convert it into stream. I have tried with RenderTargetBitmap. But it doesnot work, Is there any possible other ways for it?

```
     private async void ConverteToImage(UIElement element, int pageIndex)         
       {

        RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();

        await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(element); // Render canvas.
        var pixelBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
        var logicalDpi = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi;
        using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
            encoder.SetPixelData(
            BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
            BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
            (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
            (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
            logicalDpi,
            logicalDpi,
            pixelBuffer.ToArray());
            await encoder.FlushAsync();
            SaveAsCustomStamp(stream.AsStream(), pageIndex, loadedDocument);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using a `RenderTargetBitmap`, you can accomplish scenarios such as applying image effects to a visual that originally came from a **XAML** UI composition.

Comment: The better way is that you could convert it's parent (Xaml) to RenderTargetBitmap.